# PHP How to find missing Serial Numbers Into Alphanumeric series

Tags: php, arrays, numbers, alphanumeric

I have XML file from which i can generate PHP array of all Serial Numbers.

My requirements is to find ALL MISSING serial numbers in that array list.

**We can find missing number into INTEGER numbers of array as following**

```
$sr_array = array("1","2","5","9");

$sr_range = range(min($sr_array),max($sr_array)); 

$missing = array_diff($sr_range,$sr_array);
```

Above code will give result as ("3","4","6","7","8")

**Main issue is that the serial numbers are in AlphaNumeric series.**

```
$sr_array = array("NT1846U6000018",
"NT1846U6000019",
"NT1850U6000033",
"NT1923U6000002",
"NT1941U6023833");
```

Output series should be like following ( Series Start to End ) but without array elements provided in above example.

Step - 1 : First element of array is "NT1846U6000018" and Last element of array is "NT1941U6023833" and need to find all array element between them. We can assume here that characters element within series will stay same. ie. NTxxxxUxxxxxxx

Step - 2 : Remove array elements which we already found into XML file.

```
NT1846U6000018

...

...

NT1941U6023833
```

Can anyone help me to create PHP function to find missing series numbers.

Thanks

Comment: This is going to be difficult because there doesn't seem to be a way to figure out the range of the serial numbers to determine which ones are missing.

Comment: Given your example data, what would you expect the output to be?

Comment: Thanks for comments. I have updated question with desired output and steps to find them.